# Get local time representation of Date in arbitrary timezone in arbitrary day - considering Daylight Savings Time

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, dst

For sure, there is a [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805613/javascript-countdown-using-absolute-timezone) about [`Date`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664869/time-zone-sensitive-date-and-time-display-in-web-applications) [objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207655/how-to-get-time-of-specific-timezone-using-javascript) and [timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106270/using-timezone-other-than-browser-zone-in-javascript) but many of them are about converting the *current* time to another timezone, and others are not very clear about what they want to do.

I want to display the day, hour, minute etc. in an arbitrary timezone, in an arbitrary day. For example, I would like a function `f(t, s)` that:

- given the timestamp 1357041600 (which is 2013/1/1 12:00:00 UTC) and the string `"America/Los Angeles"`, would satisfy the comparison below:

  ```
  f(1357041600, "America/Los Angeles") == "2013/01/01 04:00:00"
  ```
- given the timestamp 1372680000 (2013/07/01 12:00:00 UTC), would satisfy the comparison below:

  ```
  f(1357041600, "America/Los Angeles") == "2013/07/01 05:00:00"
  ```
- will always behave this way even if the timezone in the browser is, let us say `"Europe/London"` or `"America/São Paulo"`.
- will always behave this way even if the time in the browser is, let us say 2014/02/05 19:32, or 2002/08/04 07:12; and
- as a final restriction, will not request anything from the server side (because I'm almost doing it myself :) )

Is it even possible?

Comment: Yes possible. Either find a library that already does it, good chance with something like [moments.js](http://momentjs.com/) or if doing it yourself, grab the [tz database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) (a.k.a. Olson database) convert the data to a javascript object and use it as a lookup for your function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize javascript date to a particular timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-javascript-date-to-a-particular-timezone)

Comment: See specifically my answer in that dup post for a list of libraries that solve this exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

For JavaScript runtime environments that support the [ECMAScript Internationalization API](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/), and adhere to its recommendation of supporting the [IANA time zone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones),  you can simply do this:

```
new Date(1357041600000).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"})
```

For other environments, a library is required.  [There are several listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824).

Answer (score 1):

> given the timestamp 1357041600 (which is 2013/1/1 12:00:00 UTC)

That appears to be seconds since the UNIX epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). Javascript uses the same epoch, but in milliseconds so to create a suitable date object:

```
var d = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
```

That will create a Date object with a suitable time value. You then need to determine the time zone offset using something like the [IANA time zone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones). That can be applied to the Date object using UTC methods. E.g. resolve the offset to minutes, then use:

```
d.setUTCMinutes(d.getUTCMinutes() + offset)
```

UTC methods can then be used to get the adjusted date and time values to create a string in whatever format you require:

```
var dateString = d.getUTCFullYear() + '/' + pad(d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '/' ...
```

where *pad* is a function to add a leading zero to single digit values. Using UTC methods avoids any impact of local time zone offsets and daylight saving variances.

There are also libraries like [timezone.js](https://npmjs.org/package/timezone-js) that can be used to determine the offset, however I have not used them so no endorsement is implied.